# SSRS Web Reference Service Not Found

Tags: ssrs, visual-studio

I'm attempting to add a Web Reference to my Visual Studio Web API to link my existing SSRS server to said API. I'm on the Add Web Reference page and I enter the proper URL and the webpage appears in the view window but for some reason it's not finding any services.

[image]

Is there something special I have to do in order to enable this functionality?

Comment: Have you followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/net-framework/building-applications-using-the-web-service-and-the-net-framework?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: Step 1 of that guide is literally what I'm trying to do right now and getting the above issue.

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio as an administrator? Also, try the url in lowercase.

Comment: Running VS as admin and entering the URL in lowercase had no effect. :(

Comment: Are you running VS as admin all the time?

Comment: Yes. I'm on a local administrator account as well.